# test user can view a login form

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm new to testing with Laravel and im testing someone else's application
im trying to simply test whether a user can view a login form

So far i have this

```
class LoginTest extends TestCase
{
    public function test_user_can_view_a_login_form()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/login');

        $response->assertSuccessful();
        $response->assertViewIs('auth.login');
    }
}
```

But i have an undefined method 'get' and i cant figure out what the issue is ive also tried Route::get but i get an error with that as well

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: Where did you define this? in unit or feature tests?

Comment: i defined it in unit

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend from Laravel TestCase that is placed in tests folder. Now, you're using phpunit Testcase which haven't basic setup for http request and many others laravel tools.

Follow below steps:

1. Create a feature test using `php artisan make:test LoginTest`
2. Define your `test_user_can_view_a_login_form` method in it.

Comment: I did do that i used that command and have that method within login test
its tests\Unit\LoginTest.php

Comment: It should be in `Tests\Feature` namespace and the class must extends from `Tests\TestCase` not `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase`